# Loading dynamic HTML from WPF browser control

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf

I am using WPF webbrowser in my project and I am trying to catch the HTML of the page. Here is the code for the same

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.uptodate.com/contents/lassa-fever/print");
}

private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic doc = webBrowser.Document;
    var htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;           
    MessageBox.Show(htmlText);
}
```

Now the problem here is:
The messagebox shows content of the page correctly but if I refer to value of htmlText in my code it doesn't show whole content but it shows only that HTML content that has been added statically excluding the content inserted using javascript.

The most weird thing I have observed here is the htmlText shows different output for different visualizers i.e. when htmlText is viewed using text visualizer it shows only static content of page but when it is viewed using HTML visualizer it shows all expected content including HTML loaded using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :-

```
HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML");
        if (elems.Count == 1)
        {
            elem = elems[0];
            string Code = elem.OuterHtml;
        }
```

**Edited:**

You can also try below code :-

```
var renderedHtml = doc.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feed back I tried both the approaches bit it didn't work.
The Code variable in your first approach and renderedHtml in second behaves in the same way as that of my code
i.e  shows content of the page correctly but if I refer to value of htmlText in my code it doesn't show whole content but it shows only that HTML content that has been added statically excluding the content inserted using javascript

Comment: Can you try 1 thing, use a timer control with 5 seconds inside "webBrowser_LoadCompleted" and code current written inside it, write it in timer function. Means give it few seconds to load complete html.